# Is it worth to use Cobertura in web project?

Tags: java, html, testing

I have never used Cobertura or similar tools before, only JUnit (and I've checked what are mocking tools) and in recent days Selenium.
I am writing web application with full of JSP, JavaScript (jQuery) and HTML. Can Cubertura helps me in these areas or this tools covered only plain Java classes?

Answer (score 0):

Coberatura apparently only deals with coverage of your Java codebase.  There's no obvious reason why it only would work with JUnit tests.  You should be able to determine the overage of other tests (including Selenium tests) that exercise your server-side Java code.

There are apparently Javascript coverage tools (e.g. [JSCoverage](http://siliconforks.com/jscoverage/)) that may be useful for testing the client-side coverage of your Selenium tests ... for the Javascript / JQuery parts.

HTML coverage doesn't immediately make sense to me, and I don't know how you'd deal with that.